# Software for Linux that disables trackpad while typing?

Tags: linux, mouse, keyboard, accessibility

**Problem:** When I type, my thumb pad(?) brushes on the trackpad of my laptop.

Windows has a feature that I turned on to **temporarily disable the mouse while typing.** I am looking for similar software or hidden settings to do the same in a linux-base operating system. I am using an Ubuntu 16 derivative called [Zorin OS](https://zorinos.com).

Is there anything that can prevent me from clicking and typing in random places?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762189/disable-touchpad-while-typing-option-gone-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts and https://askubuntu.com/questions/773595/how-can-i-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-ubuntu-16-04-syndaemon-isnt-working and https://askubuntu.com/questions/462135/touchpad-issue-jumping-cursor-while-typing-ubuntu-14-04-syndaemon-dont-help/723954#723954